# SQL Insert from Select to same table but with a changed ID - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I need to copy a number of rows from a table that have the same id_shop value, then insert these rows back into the same table but with a different id_shop value. I'm not sure how to do the later part. I'm guessing that it will be a variation of the following.

```
  INSERT INTO `ps_hook_module`(`id_module`, `id_shop`, `id_hook`, `position`)
  SELECT `id_module`, `id_shop`, `id_hook`, `position` FROM `ps_hook_module` WHERE     
  `id_shop` = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO `ps_hook_module`(`id_module`, `id_shop`, `id_hook`, `position`)
SELECT `id_module`, 42, `id_hook`, `position` FROM `ps_hook_module` 
WHERE `id_shop` = 1
```

42 is a different id_shop value you wanted

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realize that I could just through in the new id with the select items like that.